# Is there a way to prevent wp_head from outputting self-closing tags?

Tags: theme-development, actions, html, validation, wp-head

I'm a beginner in WP development, so maybe I'm missing something obvious.

**Is there a way to prevent wp_head from outputting self-closing tags?**

Here are two example lines taken from my website:

```
<meta name='robots' content='max-image-preview:large, max-snippet:-1, max-video-preview:-1' />↩
<link rel='stylesheet' id='underboot-style-css'  href='https://example.com/wp-content/themes/underboot-child/style.css?ver=6.0.2' media='all' />↩
```

This triggers a warning in the W3 Validator:

> Self-closing tag syntax in text/html documents is widely discouraged;
> it’s unnecessary and interacts badly with other HTML etc.

Not exactly a deal breaker but I'd really like to have clean, valid HTML code.

Thank you for any tips!